# ImageMagick Draw translate coordinates

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I have generated a polygon using coordinates, which is stored in an `ImagickDraw` object. I would like to rotate a few copies of the object and then draw them at various positions onto my image.

I am using imagick 3.1.0rc1 and ImageMagick 6.7.6-5.

Here's what I am using:

```
$sprite = new ImagickDraw();
$sprite->polygon($coords) //array of coordinates

$sprite->rotate(-90); //Doesn't seem to rotate
$sprite->translate($x, $y); //Doesn't seem to translate

$im->drawImage($sprite);
```

The problem is that for some reason, `rotate` and `translate` does nothing. Am I doing something wrong? Or does `rotate` and `translate` not do what I think it's suppose to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like translate was not the way to do it.

I ended up generating the sprite in a new `ImagickDraw` object and then drew it onto my main image using `compositeImage()` into the appropriate position.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, you have to apply the rotation/translation **before** you do the drawing.